# ChartKick Show original value rather percentage in PIE and line chart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, chartkick

I've data like

```
graph_data = {
  "Commercial"=>364,
  "Residential"=>463,
  "Hospitality"=>150,
  "Industrial"=>20,
  "Laboratory"=>1
}
pie_chart graph_data
```

when I add this in the pie chart, it displays the chart with percentage of each option, I wan to display the value rather percentage, How i can do this,

I'm using Chartkick gem with ruby on rails 4

Answer (score 1):

`Chartkick` uses Google Visualization library to draw charts. Here is options description: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart?csw=1#Example

```
pie_chart graph_data, { pieSliceText: 'value' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the syntax I found that worked:

```
<%= pie_chart @my_data, library: { pieSliceText: 'value' } %>
```

I found this answer over at https://stackoverflow.com/a/35199044 and tested it successfully.