# How to show count of data along with percentage in chartkicks in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, chartkick

Using `chartkicks` for showing charts. It show percentage only . I want to show count/amount along with percentage.

```
<%= pie_chart visits.group(:country).count %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Chartkick` gem is a wrapper on top of `Google Charts`. By using library option you can specify what value to show in the `legend` and set other configuration options.

So something like:

```
<%= pie_chart visits.group(:country).count, library: {pieSliceText:
'value-and-percentage'} %>
```

See this link for more configuration options: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#configuration-options

Comment: From where you get this ", library: {pieSliceText:
'value-and-percentage'}".

Comment: This is currently undocumented but if you look at the library code you will find this option as i also had to use it in one of my projects before. So use it at your own discretion.