# Rails, Chartkick: Show values on the charts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

The [Chartkick](https://www.chartkick.com/) gem lets you create many kinds of charts. Currently, my charts look like this:

> pie_chart @institutions

[image]

> column_chart @stats

[image]

I want that values are shown on the charts. In the pie chart, I want the number 244 and 43 be visible in or outside of the pie chart. In the column chart, I'd like to have the values on top or in the column. Is this somehow possible?

Regarding to the pie chart, there is already a [stackoverflow-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35197744/how-to-show-count-of-data-along-with-percentage-in-chartkicks-in-rails), but the accepted answer does nothing for me:

> pie_chart visits.group(:country).count, library: {pieSliceText:
>   'value-and-percentage'}

I tried to add the option

> library: {pieSliceText: 'value-and-percentage'}

but nothing changed. What am I doing wrong? Is there maybe an option or setting that I am missing?

There is another, similar [stackoverflow-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965684/chartkick-show-original-value-rather-percentage-in-pie-and-line-chart?rq=1), in which following solutions were proposed:

> `<%= pie_chart @my_data, library: { pieSliceText: 'value' } %>`

and

```
pie_chart graph_data, { pieSliceText: 'value' }
```

But both didn't work for me. Is there maybe a new syntax?

EDIT 1:

```
<% data = [['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]] %>

<%= pie_chart data, library: { pieSliceText: 'value' } %>
```

gives me this:

[image]

EDIT 2: Chartkick proposes 3 ways to install Chartkick. I chose the first one with Chart.js. Due to the helpful comments, I now installed the second way. Now, my Pie-Charts have numbers shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this and it is working fine

```
<% data = [['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]] %>

<%= pie_chart data, library: { pieSliceText: 'value' } %>
```

[image]

What is the structure of `@institutions`, may be that's causing some issue.

UPDATE:: on column chart

The GH for chartkick says there is no official support for showing data on each column yet
https://github.com/ankane/chartkick.js/issues/38#issuecomment-271117774

Comment: I don't get the same. Check my edit. Maybe I didn't include Chartkick properly?

Comment: chartkick (1.3.2) using default google chart adaptor. are you using any custom adaptor

Comment: check initializer chartkick.rb if you are setting something globablly

Comment: including is straight forward, 1. add gem 2. include chartkick and google chart apis and 3. render chart (`pie_chart ...`)

Comment: <%= javascript_include_tag "https://www.google.com/jsapi" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "chartkick" %>

Comment: Chartkick proposes 3 ways to install Chartkick. I chose the first one "Chart.js". Now, I took the second one, and it worked. Thanks. How do I create labels for the column charts?

Comment: Could you please update your answer, in regard of column charts?