# Rails Chartkick Bar Chart Customization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I'm new to charts and I have an app that is supposed to show each user's personality traits on the users' profile page based on [Watson](https://personality-insights-demo.ng.bluemix.net). Each trait is valued between 0.01 to 1.00 (perfect), for example:

```
user_id | username | password_digest | openness | idealism | environmentalist | achievement
1       | John     | some string     | 0.123    | 0.234    | 0.150            | 0.871
```

In my user view show.html.slim, I have:

```
= bar_chart user
```

[image]

How should I write bar_chart so that:

- It will only include the trait columns, and not include the created_at, updated_at, and password digest
- Set the range of the bar from 0 to 1 or 0% to 100%, based on the values of each trait

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45524226/rails-chartkick-show-values-on-the-charts) for the answer

Users controller:

```
@data = [
      ['Openness', @user.openness],
      ['Idealism', @user.idealism],
      etc..
    ]
```

Users show view:

```
= column_chart @data
= bar_chart @data
= pie_chart @data
```