# How to display label inside pie chart in Chartkick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chart.js, chartkick

I'm using Haml.

So the code is this:

```
 = pie_chart @chart_ratings, donut: true, suffix: "%", loading: "Generating charts...", download: true, width: "350px", library: {plotOptions: { pie: { dataLabels: { enabled: true }}}}
```

But the library doesn't include the labels.

Is there anything missing?

Comment: Does this perhaps answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45525644/2358409

Comment: It didn't work. I tried that before. I think it's just incompatible with Chart.js. I will try another library for chart and see what it shows.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Chart.js doesn't support labels inside of the chart. So instead, I'm using Highcharts.

1. Install the highchart. You can have both libraries in the Chartkick installation.

   yarn add highchart
2. Then you add the following into the application.js file.

   import "chartkick/highcharts"
3. Then in the view for the pie chart, you append this.

   = pie_chart @data, donut: true, library: { pieSliceText: 'value-and-percentage', plotOptions: {pie: {dataLabels: {enabled: true,format: '**{point.name}**:
   {point.percentage:.1f} %',}}}}